# Modify prefix key in spring session with Redis

Tags: spring, redis, spring-session

Anybody knows How can I change the prefix of the key in Spring Session with redis, the key is spring:session:sessions:, and the field is BOUNDED_HASH_KEY_PREFIX.

Answer (score 3):

For spring boot users, add this line to application.properties:

`spring.session.redis.namespace: your-session-namespace`

Or you can use Annotation

`@EnableReidsHttpSession(redisNamespace="your-session-namespace")`

P.S.
If you use empty `@EnableRedisHttpSession` annotation, it will override the application.properties and default the namespace back to "spring:session", very confusing behavior.

Answer (score 1):

It is called the `namespace` of the Redis session repository.

Since `RedisOperationsSessionRepository` is deprecated now, you can use `RedisIndexedSessionRepository` instead to configure the namespace in your Redis instance:

```java
/**
 * Configuring Redis repository to fine tune session storage
 */
@Bean
public RedisIndexedSessionRepository sessionRepository(RedisOperations<Object, Object> redisTemplate) {
  RedisIndexedSessionRepository sessionRepo = new RedisIndexedSessionRepository(redisTemplate);
  sessionRepo.setDefaultMaxInactiveInterval(maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds);
  sessionRepo.setDefaultSerializer(springSessionDefaultRedisSerializer());
  sessionRepo.setRedisKeyNamespace(redisNamespace);
  return sessionRepo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I extends of RedisOperationsSessionRepository, and override the property by default.